# Custom server sorting for Kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to apply custom server sorting on Kendo grid.
He are my entities:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    //other properties 
} 

public class Region 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to sort users by first region's Name in the Regions collection. For other sorting, filtering and paging `.ToDataSourceResult(request)` extension method is used but it seems that my scenario is not supported out of the box. That's why I tried to sort `IQuearable` manually first, remove `SortDescriptor` and then call `.ToDataSourceResult(request)`:

```
    private IQueryable<User> FilterByRegions(IQueryable<User> users, IList<SortDescriptor> sortings)
    {
        var regionsSort = sortings?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Member == "Regions");
        if (regionsSort == null)
            return users;

        sortings.Remove(regionsSort);

        Expression<Func<User, object>> exp = user => user.Regions.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();

        if (regionsSort.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            return users.OrderBy(exp);
        else
            return users.OrderByDescending(exp);
    }
```

Usage:

```
    public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IQueryable<User> users = _userApplicationService.GetAll();

        users = FilterByRegions(users, request.Sorts);

        DataSourceResult result = users.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

But it seems that calling `.ToDataSourceResult(request)` ignore my previous sorting.

How can I achieve desired result? Is it possible to add some custom logic to `IQueryable` before using `.ToDataSourceResult(request)`?

I know that it's possible to construct query manually using `DataSourceRequest request` but it's a bummer because I have a lot of different filters and sortings.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not ignoring. If you have other sorts you need create different expression. It is how Linq is working. Please note that you can have only one `OrderBy...`. Any further one will replace previous one. In Linq you need to use `ThenBy...`. My advice would be create projection when you will explicit send region name, and then modify request sorts to add new projection property.

Comment: You can always try something similar as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564029/kendo-grid-sort-by-nullable-property)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement where I had to implement custom server side pagination and sorting with Kendo Grid. According to [this post](https://www.telerik.com/forums/mvc-grid-ajax-paging-not-working), you should change the request parameter in the ToDataSourceResult extension method to be an empty request instead of passing in the parameter request.
So
`DataSourceResult result = users.ToDataSourceResult(request);` should be changed to  `DataSourceResult result = users.ToDataSourceResult(new DataSourceRequest());`. Doing this helped me implement the server side paging and sorting correctly.